# Pushnotification in xtify in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, xtify

In my app i have to Use Xtify for Pushnotification.

> http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Download+the+Xtify+SDKs
>   Using this i download ios sdk and register my application and got my AppKey and replace it in **XtifyGlobal.h**

Now,After that i created some Notification related to my app In TARGET Menu.[image]
My problem is i successfully received message in Inbox tab as show in image and got badge on app icon.But i don't received any sound or notification while received message.
What is my mistake or is it right what i do for xtify?

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long effort i soled my Problem.

My problem is just because of i upload wrong certificate.

> I extract iPhone Developer certificate instead of Apple Developement ios push certificate and upload it.

After change it and upload it again i received Notification and message.

Hope this will help someone.